# How can we make babeltrace survive the restart of the node and resume after restart

Tags: lttng, babeltrace

In lttng live streaming and looking at it through babeltrace; when the node restarts, it continues to send the traces but babeltrace has already done a shutdown because the flow has ended. 
So in this stage if babeltrace is restarted manually, it resumes its functionality and works fine.

But how we can make the babeltrace survive the restart and resume after restart? We need this as we post-process babeltrace output and the tests are run during the night.

Answer (score 1):

Babeltrace maintainer here!

There is currently no "retry" option in Babeltrace's live mode. If I understand correctly, you would like for Babeltrace to retry to connect to the remote relay daemon periodically after a connection is dropped? (Ungracefully, I assume)

I have no immediate recommendation except perhaps writing a shell script which re-launches Babeltrace if it exits.

Feel free to ask more questions on the lttng-dev@lists.lttng.org mailing list.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: But how babeltrace differentiate the restart of the node (in this case babeltrace should have to retry to connect to the remote) and closing the remote connection completely (this time babeltrace should not retry to connect ). Thanks for your response which helps me a lot.

Comment: @Gilsha, as you might have noticed, I don't have enough internet points to comment on the question. The answer, stated more concisely, is "it's not supported".